# python selenium detect alert error si active

Tags: python, selenium

on this [page](https://secure.ingdirect.it/login.aspx) when digit wrong data open alert error, i need check if this alert is open, if is open need close, im write this code bat not working :

example alert image : http://snag.gy/8WM0q.jpg

my actual code :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://secure.ingdirect.it/login.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtCodiceCliente").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtCodiceCliente").send_keys('1234567')
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtgg").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtgg").send_keys("01")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtmm").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtmm").send_keys("01")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtaaaa").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_txtaaaa").send_keys("1999")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphContenuto_LoginContainerUC1_LoginStepCifUC1_lnbvanti").click()

if self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "chiudi"):
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("chiudi").click()
    return
```

how i can check if this alert exist, and close it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use following code to check whether pop-up appears or not (close pop-up if it is opened or do nothing if there is no pop-up):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="popuptipo1chiudi close"]').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```